# Coldfusion - Overriding tag based functions that use keywords

Tags: inheritance, coldfusion

I am currently trying to extend a thirdparty CFC, it is all going fine and working correctly, however, I have now come to override one of the methods in the CFC (the whole reason I am extending it in the first place). Now the third party CFC is all tag based, and has a function named "do" - defined as follows:

```
<cffunction name="do" returntype="any" access="public" output="true" 
                hint="I compile and execute a specific fuseaction.">
        <cfargument name="action" type="string" required="true" 
                    hint="I am the full name of the requested fuseaction (circuit.fuseaction)." />
        <cfargument name="contentVariable" type="string" default="" 
                    hint="I indicate an attributes / event scope variable in which to store the output." />
        <cfargument name="returnOutput" type="boolean" default="false" 
                    hint="I indicate whether to display output (false - default) or return the output (true)." />
        <cfargument name="append" type="boolean" default="false" 
                    hint="I indicate whether to append output (false - default) to the content variable." />
        <cfargument name="passThroughReturn" type="boolean" default="false" 
                    hint="I indicate whether to allow for a return to be passed through from an action CFC." />
```

Now, my CFC is all cfscript (my personal preference & project coding standards). If I try to override this method in my CFC as follows:

```
public any function do( Required String action, String contentVariable="", boolean returnOutput=false, boolean append=false, boolean passThroughReturn=false){
```

Then I get an error about the function name, assumed because "do" is a CF reserved word.

I have tried to get around this by renaming the method and just mapping do it, e.g.:

```
this.do = variables.invokeDo;

public any function invokeDo( Required String action, String contentVariable="", boolean returnOutput=false, boolean append=false, boolean passThroughReturn=false){
```

This gets around the error, but if I call `myObject.do(..)` it just invokes the super class method.

Does anyone know how I can override this method in CFscript?

Comment: Strangely, I have covered this very point (I think) in my blog today: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/07/reserved-words-or-not-make-up-yer-mind.html. I haven't tested with `do()` but I presume it's at least the same *sort of* issue..?

Comment: Yep, it looks like the very same issue - it looks like there isn't/you didnt find a fix whilst using cfscript in CF (not railo)?

Comment: There's no "fix". It's just ColdFusion being crap. It's at the compiler level, so there's no way to make it work, you just have to not use that syntax. You can't achieve this in CFScript, you wil need to use tags in this case.  :-(

Comment: Ya, shouldn't have used reserved word `do` as function name, but in defense of that 3rd party, `do` was not outlined in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec173d0-7ff8.html

Comment: @Henry - It is [mentioned here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html). Unfortunately using a commonly reserved word like `do` is just asking for trouble .. Gotta' love working with 3rd party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a good way to accomplish what you want. However, there are a few workarounds. One hack is to do this:

```
component extends="OriginalComponent" {
  variables["do"] = function () {
    // new function code here
  };

  this["do"] = variables["do"];
}
```

It doesn't *actually* override the function in the traditional sense, but it *seems* to work: when testing, both internal and external calls to the function called the new function, not the original.

There may be additional ramifications to this sort of hack that I'm not aware of, so be careful.

Comment: Workaround works at the moment. Will see if I find any unwanted side effects.

Comment: Ok, I have found one apparent side-effect - If at any point in the overriding function i want to hand it off to the parent component function, it doesn't work - In the context of the child function, "super" is not recognised.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use CFML, this may work if your new cfc needs not to be typed checked, and you don't need to access parent's private variables.

```
component {

  function init(parent) {
    variables.parent = parent;
    return this;
  }

  function onMissingMethod(missingMethodName, missingMethodArguments)
  {
    if (missingMethodName == "do")
      doFunc();
    else {
      // if CF10, use invoke(), else use yucky evaluate()
    }
  }

  function doFunc()
  {
     // your new do() function
  }
}
```